# What can I do to make sure plaice filet doesn't get dry?

Tags: fish

I just cooked myself some plaice in both butter and oil. It didn't feel like I cooked it too long, but still the fish tasted pretty dry.

Is there something I can do or pay attention to in order to prevent this from happening?

Comment: It is almost certainly that they are being overcooked.  Fish goes from not done to overcooked very quickly.  Lower the heat, go slow, monitor closely.

Comment: And don't forget, even fish will "carryover" cook, meaning that it will continue to cook for a short time after you remove it from the heat. Remove it from the heat when it is ever-so-slightly *underdone*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly consider a lower temprature but do start with a very hot pan, and turn down the heat and make sure you baste your fish correctly; cook skin side for a longer time, untill you have the desired colour. Add your butter and let it foam, and only then turn your fish. Once you have turned your fish you can take your pan off the heat. Start basting with foamy butter. For plaice, It should be done in under 1 minute. If your not serving straight away remove from pan for hot holding. 
If you keep to do this method, its hard to end up with a dry fish.

Comment: I kind of took your advice. Since I live in a student house and we have an oldskool electric stove here, I cooked it short on high heat and finished it in 160C oven. It worked :)